# Initiating a method in a class

Tags: python, django

I'm new to both Django and Python.. I just started using them a few days ago and I can't quite figure out how to call a method other than the `__init__` method for a class.

Here is the code for user.py

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.num = number

class Create:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.test = something[1]

    def other(self, one):
        self.two = one
```

I can get `__init__` to work by calling..

```
list = [3, 4, 5]
y = Create(list)
arrayelem = y.test
```

But I can't quite figure out how to call a method inside of the class Create.  I've tried various methods and always end up with errors.  Can somehow show me some syntactically correct methods of calling the method "other".

Note:  I know the spacing is weird.. I can't get the spacing to work properly on stackoverflow for whatever reason..

Comment: Your spacing is screwed up because you're using tabs, not spaces for indentation. You need to always use spaces.

Comment: I've just edited the question (pending approval) so that it uses all spaces, and no tabs. You'll soon get used to not mixing spaces and tabs if you're embarking upon Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news - it's a simple one! To call other() on create, you'd do this:

```
list = [3, 4, 5]
y = Create(list)
y.other('one')
```

You just need to pass the parameters inside the parentheses, after the name of the method.

**EDIT:** I've just noticed you want to call `other` from inside the `Create` class. That'd look like this:

```
class Create:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.test = something[1]
        self.other(123)

    def other(self, one):
        self.two = one
```

It's also worth bearing in mind that `self.two` won't exist when you get to the `other()` method.

Comment: Okay.. so if i use 
`list = [3, 4, 5]
y = Create(list)
z = y.other('1')
arrayelem = z.two`
  I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'two'

Comment: OK, I just edited my answer to mention this problem - you need to initiate `self.two` to something in `Create.__init__()`. That way, you won't be trying to change something that doesn't exist (ie. a NoneType object) when you get to `other()`.

Comment: so basically, I need to initiate whatever variables i want to call in other.. in __init__ ?  I'm coming from a Java and PHP background, so this is all pretty foreign to me.

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html) out, which explains it better than I ever could here. And if I've answered your question, don't forget to accept it (it's the big green tick button).